# How can I add a hyperlink to a text in adobe xd?

Tags: fonts, website-design, adobe-xd

I cannot add a hyperlink in adobe xd text. I want a text which should show a hyperlink on drag or onclick of it.

Like we can do in Figma by clicking the **(CTRL + K)** key.
So my question is how can we do the same in adobe xd?

Thank You.

Comment: See the Adobe Help page where this is documented. https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/xd/help/create-hyperlinks.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is one. https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/keyboard-shortcuts.html

Documentation on creating hyperlinks:
https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/create-hyperlinks.html

Comment: Dear @Brennan this is not the proper solution for my question, you are showing me another question and some shortcut keys which I already saw before asking this question.

Comment: @SumitYadav Apologies, I must have not understood correctly.  Have you seen how to do this in the prototype context? https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/create-hyperlinks.html — even still it does not look like that there is a shortcut for this.

Answer (score 0):

From the Adobe documentation "You can't hyperlink inline text". But you can create a hyperlink for a text box.